# how to decrypt .ldcw files (Lynda offline video)

Tags: video, encryption, download, windows-store-apps, windows

I have downloaded a Lynda course from the windows Lynda App. The videos are stored in the App Data folder in C: drive.

These files have .ldcw file extension, so not able to play with VLC player. After doing some research found a tool (https://github.com/h4ck-rOOt/Lynda-Decryptor) to decrypt the video. But it doesn't work with .ldcw files.

- Is there any other way to decrypt the files?
- If not decrypt, suggestions on easier ways to download the entire Lynda course (GUI or cmd)?

Answer (score 1):

Yo actually really don't need to go through the hassle of decrypting the files downloaded offline. Simply install IDM (Internet Download Manager) on your system. It will download them for you from the secure file on Lynda.com. See proof below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaPjp.jpg)

Comment: this is for each video. I want it for downloading the entire course